# Orchard Simple Widget Not Saving database values

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

I've been having a little problem creating a simple widget. All I want to do is create a widget that has the a MediaPickerField and 2 int and 2 string fields that are stored in the database using a part. Everything works as advertised. ContentRecord is created and the image field is properly stored, except that the four fields are not being stored. There are no error in the logs and cannot seem to see why this is happening.  Has anyone come across this before?  Thank you.

Migration.cs

```
public int UpdateFrom1()
    {
        SchemaBuilder.CreateTable("SchoenNavButtonPartRecord",
            table => table.ContentPartRecord()
                          .Column<string>("Url", col=> col.WithLength(2140))
                          .Column<string>("Text")
                          .Column<int>("ButtonWidth")
                          .Column<int>("ButtonHeight"));
        ContentDefinitionManager.AlterTypeDefinition("SchoenNavButton", builder => 
            builder.WithPart("CommonPart")
                   .WithPart("SchoenNavButtonPart")
                   .WithPart("TitlePart")
                   .Creatable());
        ContentDefinitionManager.AlterPartDefinition("SchoenNavButtonPart", builder => 
            builder.WithField("ButtonImage", field=> 
                field.OfType("MediaPickerField")
                    .WithDisplayName("Button Image")
                    .WithSetting("Hint", "Select Image for Button")));
        return 2;
    }
```

PartRecord

```
public class SchoenNavButtonPartRecord : ContentPartRecord
{
    public virtual string Url { get; set; }
    public virtual string Text { get; set; }
    public virtual int ButtonWidth { get; set; }
    public virtual int ButtonHeight { get; set; }
}
```

Part

```
public class SchoenNavButtonPart : ContentPart<SchoenNavButtonPartRecord>
{
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }

    [DefaultValue(296)]
    public int ButtonWidth { get; set; }

    [DefaultValue(188)]
    public int ButtonHeight { get; set; }
}
```

Handler

```
public class SchoenNavButtonHandler : ContentHandler
{
    public SchoenNavButtonHandler(IRepository<SchoenNavButtonPartRecord> buttonImageLinkRepository)
    {
        Filters.Add(StorageFilter.For(buttonImageLinkRepository));
    }

}
```

Driver

```
public class SchoenNavButtonPartDriver : ContentPartDriver<SchoenNavButtonPart>
{
    public SchoenNavButtonPartDriver()
    {

    }
    protected override string Prefix
    {
        get
        {
            return "SchoenNavButton";
        }
    }
    protected override DriverResult Display(SchoenNavButtonPart part, string displayType, dynamic shapeHelper)
    {
        var fields = ((ContentPart) part).Fields.OfType<MediaPickerField>();
        MediaPickerField mediaPickerField = null;
        if(fields.Any())
        {
            mediaPickerField = fields.ElementAt(0);
        }
        return ContentShape("Parts_SchoenNavButton",
                         () => shapeHelper.Parts_SchoenNavButton(
                             SchoenNavButtonPart: part,
                             ImageUrl: mediaPickerField == null ? "#" : mediaPickerField.Url
                                   ));
    }
    protected override DriverResult Editor(SchoenNavButtonPart part, dynamic shapeHelper)
    {
        return ContentShape("Parts_SchoenNavButton_Edit", () =>
            shapeHelper.EditorTemplate(
                TemplateName: "Parts/SchoenNavButton",
                Model: part,
                Prefix: Prefix));
    }
    protected override DriverResult Editor(SchoenNavButtonPart part, Orchard.ContentManagement.IUpdateModel updater, dynamic shapeHelper)
    {
        updater.TryUpdateModel(part, Prefix, null, null);
        return Editor(part, shapeHelper);
    }
}
```

EditorTemplage

```
@model FishySoftware.SchoenBuilders.Models.SchoenNavButtonPart

<fieldset>
    <legend>Button Details</legend>
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Url, T("Url"))
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Url)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Url)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Text, T("Text"))
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Text)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Text)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ButtonWidth, T("Button Width"))
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ButtonWidth)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ButtonWidth)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ButtonHeight, T("Button Height"))
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ButtonHeight)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ButtonHeight)
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Put a breakpoint in the post editor method and check whether the call to TryUpdatemodel is actually changing part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Orchard is always using content of `Record` classes to save data to the database. You, on the other hand, are saving data from the browser inside the `Part` class and you haven't properly connected your `Part` and `Record` classes.

To do that, you'll have to change your `ShoenNavButtonPart` to this:

```
public class SchoenNavButtonPart : ContentPart<SchoenNavButtonPartRecord>
{
    public string Url { 
        get { return Record.Url; } 
        set { Record.Url = value; }
    }

    public string Text { 
        get { return Record.Text; } 
        set { Record.Text = value; }
    }

    [DefaultValue(296)]
    public int ButtonWidth { 
        get { return Record.ButtonWidth; } 
        set { Record.ButtonWidth = value; }
    }

    [DefaultValue(188)]
    public int ButtonHeight { 
        get { return Record.ButtonHeight; } 
        set { Record.ButtonHeight = value; }
    }
}
```